# How to send the text file (or string to textArea in QML) from python to QML application?

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I want to send string content (multiple lines) from Python to QML application in the text area. So how I can do this.

**test.py**

```
def send_file(file_content)
    pass // send file to QML text area
```

**test.qml**

```
Window {
    id: mainWindow
    property alias text: textArea.text

    function read_file(){
        mainWindow.text = send_file(file_content) //Strings from python
    }

    TextArea{
         id: textArea
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send information from `Python` to `QML` you must create a class that inherits from `QObject` and have a `q-property` to store that value, then export an object of that class to `QML` with `setContextProperty()`, and on the `QML` side it performs a binding as shown to continuation:

**main.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtProperty, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class Helper(QObject):
    textChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self._text = ""

    @pyqtProperty(str, notify=textChanged)
    def text(self):
        return self._text

    @text.setter
    def text(self, v):
        if self._text == v:
            return
        self._text = v
        self.textChanged.emit()

    def send_file(self, file_content):
        self.text = file_content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    helper = Helper()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("helper", helper)
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile('main.qml'))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    helper.send_file("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ornare magna felis. Nulla justo ipsum, finibus eu nibh quis, iaculis malesuada lorem. Phasellus et lacus malesuada, aliquam enim condimentum, efficitur sapien. Sed ultricies egestas massa, nec sodales neque mattis et. Praesent euismod pretium hendrerit. Maecenas non porttitor velit, non scelerisque quam. Phasellus at diam vel enim venenatis vulputate sed a nisl. Sed erat nunc, maximus varius justo vitae, vehicula porttitor enim. Maecenas vitae sem odio. Nunc interdum sapien vitae magna tempus, nec laoreet elit placerat. Nullam cursus metus facilisis pulvinar auctor.")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true

    TextArea{
         id: textArea
         anchors.fill: parent
         text: helper.text
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @RohanMukundMiraje 
What happened?